# is there a way of writing a text document to the screen and search for specific words within the document and print out those words

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
document.getElementById('inputfile').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('output').textContent = fr.result;
  }
  fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
})
```

```html
<input type="file" name="inputfile" id="inputfile">
<br>

<pre id="output"></pre>
```

this is my existing code to get a documents content onto the screen

Comment: Would you like to extract specific words from the text document and print out to the screen?

Comment: @julius yeah or have a list of words that the program checks if it contains and says yes or no to containing those specific words

Answer (score 1):

The `fr.result` is a string. You can split this string into an array of words using `String.split(' ')`. And check if any of these words is a match to your pre-defined words which should be in array too using `Array.some(checkingFunction)`.
Here is the continuation of your codes

```
let myWords = ['hello', 'world', 'what', 'is', 'happening'];
function checkIfWordExistInmyWords(word){
   return myWords.includes(word);
 }
let docWords = fr.result.split(' ');
console.log(docWords.some(checkIfWordExistInmyWords))
```

Comment: error i recieve stating fr not being defined